# Trying to connect django and ms sql 2019 with django-mssql-backend

Tags: sql-server, django, database

I've got this error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't
> an available database backend. Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX',
> where XXX is one of:
> 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
>
> ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',

pip freeze shows me this:

```
asgiref==3.7.2
distlib==0.3.7
Django==4.2.4
django-mssql==1.8
django-mssql-backend==2.8.1
filelock==3.12.3
mssql-django==1.3
platformdirs==3.10.0
pytz==2023.3
sqlparse==0.4.4
tzdata==2023.3
virtualenv==20.24.3
```

i tried use 'mssql' engine, but it doesn't work too

Comment: Have you considered choosing a single SQL Server library? `mssql-django` is a fork of `django-mssql-backend`, so mixing the two in the same project isn't going to work well. Likely you don't want to use `django-mssql` at all, since it uses ADO instead of ODBC and will therefore be Windows-bound, but also because its Bitbucket repository hasn't been updated in over five years so is likely abandonware.